# Trying to calculate month over month headcount, but DAX measure is only counting EmployeeID once

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to take employee information and create a dashboard that tracks month over month headcount. I have columns for Hire Date, Termination Date, and Transfer In date.

What I'd like to do is write a measure in PowerPivot that will give me the active headcount for each month (then one for new hires, transfers, and terminations) so I can plot them on a graph to see the headcount each month.

The issue I'm running into is my measure for active headcount is only counting each employee one time as opposed to each month they are active. Ex. all employees that were hired in Jan 2021 are being counted in the pivot table, but then are not counted in the subsequent months even if still active.

Here is the code I'm working with right now:

```
ActiveEmployees:=
CALCULATE(
 COUNTROWS(TableName),
 FILTER(
  TableName,
  (  
   NOT(ISBLANK([HireDate]) && [HireDate] < MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
  &&
  (
   ISBLANK([TransferDate]) || [TransferDate] < MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
  &&
  (
   ISBLANK([TermDate]) || [TermDate] > MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
 )
)
```

I've tried a handful of other things like using ALL(TableName) and VALUES(TableName[EmployeeID]) but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be incredible!

Posting the code again here. I've pretty much used a bunch of ChatGPT to help with ideation which could have taken me in a completely wrong direction.

```
ActiveEmployees:=
CALCULATE(
 COUNTROWS(TableName),
 FILTER(
  TableName,
  (  
   NOT(ISBLANK([HireDate]) && [HireDate] < MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
  &&
  (
   ISBLANK([TransferDate]) || [TransferDate] < MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
  &&
  (
   ISBLANK([TermDate]) || [TermDate] > MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have a relationship between `TableName` and `DimDate`. If so you will need to cater for that in the measure.

Try `REMOVEFILTERS`:

```
ActiveEmployees:=
CALCULATE(
 COUNTROWS(TableName),
 REMOVEFILTERS(DimDate),
 FILTER(
  TableName,
  (  
   NOT(ISBLANK([HireDate]) && [HireDate] < MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
  &&
  (
   ISBLANK([TransferDate]) || [TransferDate] < MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
  &&
  (
   ISBLANK([TermDate]) || [TermDate] > MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
 )
)
```

Or `ALL`:

```
ActiveEmployees:=
COUNTROWS(
 FILTER(
  ALL(TableName),
  (  
   NOT(ISBLANK([HireDate]) && [HireDate] < MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
  &&
  (
   ISBLANK([TransferDate]) || [TransferDate] < MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
  &&
  (
   ISBLANK([TermDate]) || [TermDate] > MAX(DimDate[Date])
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for the answer!

I was able to find a workaround by creating a measure to count rows and then used calculate to find the couted rows measure along with my filter.